# Jordan measurable for closure and interior

Tags: real-analysis

Give an example of a bounded set $S\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\overline{S}$ and $\operatorname{Int}S$ are Jordan-measurable, but $S$ is not.

Jordan-measurability of a set $A$ is equivalent to the condition that $\operatorname{Bd}A$ has measure zero, where $\operatorname{Bd}A$ is a set of points that belong to neither the interior nor the exterior of $A$.

We have that $\operatorname{Int}S\subseteq S\subseteq\overline{S}$, so the desired condition is tricky to satisfy. I don't know what set $S$ to pick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's take $n = 2$, and identify $\mathbb{R}^2$ with $\mathbb{C}$ for simplicity.

Then let

$$S = \{ z : \lvert z\rvert < 1\} \cup \bigcup_{\varphi \in \mathbb{Q}} \left\{t\cdot e^{2\pi i\varphi} : t \in [1,2]\right\}.$$

Then $S$ is obviously bounded, $\operatorname{int}(S) = \{ z : \lvert z\rvert < 1\}$ and $\overline{S} = \{ z : \lvert z\rvert \leqslant 2\}$ are Jordan measurable. But $\operatorname{Bd}(S) = \{z : 1\leqslant \lvert z\rvert \leqslant 2\}$ is not a null set, so $S$ itself is not Jordan measurable.

Comment: Oh, then more simply, we can just take the rationals in $[0,1]$.

Comment: Sure, but that's not as spiky.